# Not able to view Dotty option while creating scala project in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-scala

I have Intellij IDEA. Below are the details about it.

```
 IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5
 Build #IU-172.4343.14, built on September 26, 2017
 Licensed to Rajkumar Natrajan
 JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b12 x86_64
 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
 Mac OS X 10.12.6
```

I have latest scala plugin for IntelliJ installed as well.

But when I try to create the dotty project using the documentation [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.2/getting-started-with-dotty.html), I couldn't see the option. Below is the screen shot.

[image: Screenshot with Dotty option missing]

Do I miss any settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose SBT first, then on the next step you will be able to select Dotty:

[image: dotty]

[Related ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11754).

Comment: This no longer works in IntelliJ 2018.1 (more specifically, this option isn't available in 2018.1.5).